# Странные символы в начале ajax ответа

Tags: php, ajax

При `ajax` запросе к контроллеру, получаю в ответ перед `json` набор из 6 символов - `"\uO"`. Когда делаю запрос к другом контроллеру к тому же коду, в ответе нету никаких символов. В какую сторону смотреть? Кодировка у обеих файлов с контроллерами та же. Но чтото должно же отличатся раз один отдает без знаков, другой со знаками ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если просто curl использовать? разница будет?

Comment: а если не возвращать `json` пропадают?

Comment: Проблема была в том что в конструкторе в одной из функций, где то шел вывод на экран непечатных символов. К сожалению поменять тех функций или как то узнать что это - нету возможности. Убрал вызов функций для XmlHttpRequest и теперь есть ок.